# Connect MongoDB using Nhibernate in Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-core, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Can I use nhibernate to connect MongoDb in Asp.Net Core. Do we need any additional driver to connect mongodb using nhibernate in Asp.Net Core?

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate only works with traditional SQL database providers. You can see full list here: https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-features. MongoDB is not one of those, specifically because it's a NoSQL solution. There is no way to use NHibernate with it. You should use the API provided by the MongoDb.Driver package directly.